# Object constructor invocation

Tags: c#

In C#, the constructors are executed in the order the most general-the most particular(from base to derived).Every class inherits from `Object`, and will therefore call `Object`'s parameterless constructor.My question is, does anything happen in the constructor of `Object`?

Comment: Look at the source code and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not look at [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab)?

```
    // Creates a new instance of an Object.
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
    public Object()
    {            
    }
```

I'm not sure how it can fail, given that it's empty, but it would seem that a no-op can't fail - I've not time to dig into the IL, but I would guess this is where a [newobj](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) happens and so

> OutOfMemoryException is thrown if there is insufficient memory to satisfy the request.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're saying from this that it does (because of `Cer.MayFail`), or that it doesn't do anything (because of the empty body).

Comment: Ha!  If it can fail, it does something, eh?  I've been trying to figure out exactly what.